# Передать данные из формы в dataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется класс с переменными, значения переменных записываются во второй форме через например TextBox'ы.
Проблема в том, чтобы передать эти значения или записать их в классе, после чего поместить по ячейкам в дата грид.

Comment: а в чем проблема-то? не можете получить значения `TextBox` в основной форме из другой формы?

Comment: Используйте привязки